# How to get scanner object to ask for more than 1 int?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a lottery game and I am trying to get the console to allow the user to enter 6 numbers but it only allows the user to enter 1 before it compares them to the random numbers.

Is there any way to allow the user to enter the 6 numbers without creating new int variables and than compare them to the random numbers generated?

I have the particular issue highlighted with a commented with a * icon.

Here is my code.

```
for (int i = 1; i <=6; i++) {
        Random run  = new Random();
        LottoNumbers.add(i);
        run.nextInt(49);
        //Get Users Lotto Picks
        //*Console will not ask for 6 numbers
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lottopick = scan.nextInt();         


        //prevent user from picking number higher than 49
        if (lottopick > 49) {
            System.out.println("You canonl pick numbers between 1 and 49");
        }
        //Compare User selection to random numbers generated
        System.out.println("Enter Your Six Numbers between 1 and 49");
        if (lottopick == run.nextInt(49)) {
            System.out.println("Millionaire");
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You lose");
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));
            System.out.println(run.nextInt(49));    
        }           
}
```

Please don't go ahead and make the full app because I will never learn otherwise. Thanks

Comment: "Is there any way to allow the user to enter the 6 numbers without creating new int variables" Is there a way to park 6 cars in one parking space?

Comment: @hexafraction I was looking for way to avoid creating too lines and making my code unreadable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, every input asks the same question, you should use a for loop and an array of inputs:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] lottopick = new int[6];

for(int i = 0; i < lottopick.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("Enter next lottery number: ");
  lottopick[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. That was the kind of answer I was looking. My code was getting a bit long

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it, first you need to decide how will you take input from user, here are some ways of doing it:

1. Ask user to enter a single string of comma seperated values and then split this string to get all integers.
2. User input a number and press enter and do same for n number of times.

Cheers !!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's good to see I was on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Using scanner.nextInt() you can get only one number at time.

1. you need to give scanner how many times you want.

like

first = scanner.nextInt();
 second = scanner.nextInt();

1. you can give it in a For loop

   for(int i=0;i<6;i++)

   {
         array[i] =scanner.nextInt();
       }
2. you read string using Scanner

   String s = scanner.next()

// String you can enter like 20,34,334,: After that you can split using ','

Comment: That seems pretty useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the input all on one line, you could get a string, split by the space and then parse the integers.

in psuedo-code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
string lottoNumbers;

lottoNumbers = scan.next();

stringChunks[] = lottoNumbers.Split(" ");

for(int x = 0; int < stringChunks.Size; x++){

    Integer.GetInt(stringChunks[x]);
}
```

emphasis on psuedo-code.

Comment: I am not aiming for using strings at the moment but thanks for showing me that technique. Always good to see more way to skin that cat. Thanks dckuehn.

Comment: @new2code That's totally cool.  Do what you think is best.  I just wasn't sure if having the input be one line was more important than the input being integers.

Comment: at the moment, it is just integers until the game mechanics are right. I will refine it than after if I am feeling up for it. Thanks so much for your response. I would upvote you but alas Stack Overflow deems my reputation unworthy. Thanks again

Comment: @new2code I know the feeling. I'm sure the other posters in this thread would appreciate the up-votes as well, so I threw your question an upvote to get you to 15.  It might not be a "pearl" question, but it was clear, and contained what we needed to answer it, so I think it was a good question.